# How to properly store an HWND in a ref class?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm working on a C++/CLI **library** to be used with C#.  I have a ref class (for use directly within managed code, so it has to be compatible) that stores an `HWND`, but I don't think I'm doing it right:

```cpp
public ref class MyClass {
  protected:
    HWND hWnd;
}
```

Should I be using a native pointer like that inside a ref class?  Or should I use something like `ptr<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native pointers/handles are completely safe inside ref classes. (They're just `int`s after all.) However, it would be more idiomatic to store them in the `IntPtr` class. (This is how WinForms [stores them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

Comment: Oh, okay.  (Also, I'm trying not to use `IntPtr` because it's kinda a pain)

Answer (score 2):

A handle is not a pointer, HWND is fine.  If you want C# code to derive from your class and access the handle then you need to expose it as an `IntPtr`.  Which is compatible with a handle, it is 4 bytes in 32-bit mode and 8 bytes in 64-bit mode, just like a handle.

Best to wrap it with a property to hide the conversion:

```
protected:
    property IntPtr Handle {
        IntPtr get()       { return IntPtr(hwnd); }
        void set(IntPtr h) { hwnd = (HWND)h.ToPointer(); }
    }
private:
    HWND hWnd;
```

A SafeHandle *might* be useful, the lifetime of a HWND is however not typically under your control.

Comment: Good answer, but I'm actually doing it reverse:  My managed C# code is passing an `IntPtr` to the C++ class, which is extracting the `HWND` from it.  I just needed to know if it was safe to store it in a ref class as-is, since most types require `ptr<T>`.

Comment: Sure, that's when you assign the Handle property and get to use a HWND in your C++/CLI code.  A HWND is wrapped in a struct in the winapi, not a pointer.  Most noticeable by the compiler not complaining about it.

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't know if it was safe to store an `HWND` (as opposed to `msclr::com::ptr<HWND__>` or something) in a ref class.